# Annoying IE7 problem

Tags: html, css

I am styling a Wordpress theme but has run into problem with IE7.

The first word("it") inside the paragraph/strong tag ends up to the left of the img tag when I want it BELOW the image.

My problem is that the only element I can change CSS properties here is the div, since the code inside is posted with a WYSIWYG by an blog author.

Is there anyway i can fix this problem?
I have tried lots of different settings and every other browser FF safari IE8 renders the text below the image.

```
<div style="width: 430px;">
    <h1>It is hard getting it right in IE7!</h1> 
    <p>
        <img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-4333"  src="http://xxx.xxx.xx/files/2010/03/xxx.jpg" alt="xxx" style="width: 430px; height: 600px" />
        <strong>It is hard</strong> getting it right in IE7!
    </p>
</div>
```

data.fuskbugg.se/skalman01/Ie7.png 
The important is in the element style but heres the rest.

```
strong { line-height: 16px; } 
p { 5px 0px 10px; } 
h1 { 
  font-family:"arial black","lucida console",sans-serif; font-size:30px;
  font-weight:normal; 
  line-height:31px; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0 0 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the related CSS, a screen shot or an online example?

Comment: It seems to work fine for me in both IE6 and 7 - your css further up the tree must be causing issues. Can you post this please?

Comment: http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman01/Ie7.png

The iportant is in the element style but heres the rest
strong {
  line-height: 16px; 
}

p {
   5px 0px 10px;
}

h1 {
   font-family:"arial black","lucida console",sans-serif;
   font-size:30px;
   font-weight:normal;
   line-height:31px;
   margin:0;
   padding:0 0 10px;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img.size-full {display:block;}
```

This will (should) create a line break after the image.